# Cannot print called float variables

Tags: c

I cannot print `float` variables when calling my functions. `int` variables print but floats won't print their proper value when passed to my function.

I tried to change the `float` to `int` and that worked

```c
int main() {
    int foo = 6;
    call(foo);
}

void call(int bar) {
    printf("%d", bar);
}
```

This worked and it does indeed print 6.

But, doing the same but with floats only prints out 0.00000:

```c
int main() {
    float foo = 6;
    call(foo);
}

void call(float bar) {
    printf("%f", bar);
}
```

How do I correctly call and then print float variables?

Comment: You need to add more warning options and work to a version of the C standard that was issued after you were born.  (OK: I admit I'm guessing your age, but you should be using at least C99 and really should be using C11 or C17/C18.). If you used GCC, you would want to use `-Werror -Wall -Wextra`, and you could add more options if you liked.  If you're using [GCC 5.x](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html) or later, the default standard is C11 (`-std=gnu11` to be more precise); only older versions default to C90 (no version defaulted to C99).  Using those options, your code would not compile!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply define `call` above `main` instead of below it. The compiler must have seen the declaration of functions when they are used, so a forward declaration like [pm100 suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75327662/7582247) is one way. Moving the whole definition above `main` is the another (that does not require a forward declaration).

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void call(float integerrrr){
    printf("%f", integerrrr);
}

int main(void){
    float integerrrr = 6;
    call(integerrrr);        // now the compiler knows about this function
}
```

> INT type variables i can print but float just does not

If your program actually compiles *as-is* it will use an old (obsolete) rule that makes an *implicit* declaration of undeclared functions when they are used. The implicit declaration would be `int call();` - which does not match your actual function. The program (even the one that seems to be working) therefore had *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Without a prototype in scope (which is not valid in C99 or later), the `float` value is promoted to `double` in the call (and if short integer types were involved, they'd be promoted to `int`).  But the function is defined to take a `float`, so all hell breaks loose — it's undefined behaviour, but parts of what happened are defined.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler _"all hell breaks loose"_ :-) Indeed. The expectation that the function will return `int` when it is in fact `void` can't be good either.

Comment: Also true.  Section [§6.5.2.2 Function calls](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2) of the C11 standard details the 'default argument promotions'.  That section will be substantially modified in [C23](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3054.pdf); the non-prototype function definitions will be non-standard, and functions must have a prototype (not merely a declaration) in scope before they are used.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler C23 looks like a big change. I've just browsed through some of the highlights and it seems to be many more changes than in previous revisions.  Sidequestion regarding the prototypes change: Can variadic functions have prototypes (_"A function prototype is a declaration of a function that declares the types of its parameters"_)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I see now that the above definition of what a _"function prototype"_ is also changes in C23 to _"A function prototype is a declaration of a function"_ so, they become one and the same?

Comment: Yes, and a declaration of the form `int function();` now becomes equivalent to `int function(void);` — following C++'s lead, of course.  That provides a prototype in C23; it doesn't in C17/C18.

Comment: Also, even in current C (or indeed in C90), you must have a full prototype in scope for a variadic function to avoid undefined behaviour.  So, there must be a prototype along the lines of `int variadic(…, ...);` in scope even in C90 for a variadic function.  The handling of `va_list` inside a function is different too — the last (non-variadic) argument is no longer required in the call to `va_start()`, etc.  They've made that a non-breaking change.  I think the function declarations to function prototypes could be a breaking change for some code. Yes, C23 has a lot of changes.  It will be fun.

Answer (score 3):

you need a forward declaration of call

```
void call(float integerrrr);

int main(){
  float integerrrr=6;
  call(integerrrr);
}

void call(float integerrrr){
  printf("%f", integerrrr);
}
```

your compiler probably warned you about this

Answer (score 1):

the compiler of c work from top to bottom so line by line,
so u will have to call the first function `void call()` then your main function:

```
void call(float integerrrr){
printf("%f", integerrrr);

}

int main(){
  float integerrrr=6;
  call(integerrrr);
}
```